# Do I need to anchor premade concrete stairs

Tags: stairs

Do I have to anchor premade concrete steps to the wall?  We used to have wooden steps but they were not anchored to the wall.

Comment: What are premade concrete steps? The particular type is important to any answer. Please revise to provide more information.

Comment: I live in the northeast, and my premade concrete steps did eventually end up a couple inches from the house.  Not sure if it was due to settling or frost upheaval.

Answer (score 1):

Can you move the steps easily, say if you kick them do they move.

Concrete is HEAVY.

If installed so that they are solid and do not rock then it is unlikely you need to unless they in the path of say a car or snow plow that may hit them.

I would say no but you have not given us any info about them or why you think it may be necessary.

*If you update you question with more info then that may change the answer*.